# static inline C++17 variable in MSVC 14.16 - is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, inline, static-variables

I have a following code perfectly compiling in MSVC14.13 (15.6):

```
template <typename T>
struct Quat
{
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4201 ) // warning about non-std anonymous structs

  union
  {
    struct { T x; T y; T z; T w; };
    T arr[4];
  };

#pragma warning( pop )

  Quat() {}
  Quat(T all) : x(all), y(all), z(all), w(all) {}

  static inline const Quat<T> kZero = Quat<T>(static_cast<T>(0));
};

int main()
{
  Quat<float> quat;
}
```

when I switched to MSVC 14.16 (15.9) I'm getting the following errors:

```
consoleapplication18.cpp(18): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Quat<float>'
consoleapplication18.cpp(23): note: see declaration of 'Quat<float>'
consoleapplication18.cpp(23): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Quat<float>' being compiled
```

If I comment out the `kZero` line, it compiles fine. Compiles fine also in g++10 so I'm wondering whether this is really a compiler bug?

Comment: gcc trunk also rejects it. Probably a language conformance issue that you got away with before. You can move the definition out of the class so the type is complete. `static const Quat<T> kZero;` and then after the class is complete `template<typname T>const inline Quat<T> Quat<T>::kZero = Quat<T>(0);`

Comment: Sure, this would be one way but the idea was to use the inline semantics to avoid doing exactly that. :) Btw does gcc trunk really reject it? Godbolt seems to be OK with it: https://godbolt.org/z/nqn8dv

Comment: @RaymondChen I just checked, it compiled with gcc x86-64 trunk (https://godbolt.org/z/avE3qq) and clang trunk (https://godbolt.org/z/dnTjqf). What error did you see?

Comment: Strange, the problem depends on whether Q is a template type. https://godbolt.org/z/ehrzar